# Modifying asp.net app's global visual identity without a master page

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

I've to fix an old ASP.NET application's appearance so that it can conform to the new web visual identity of my organization. The old application does not have any master page and uses a very basic .include file. Modifying the .include header does not change the overall look of the app's pages much, and I still have to manually import new css definitions,  replace the table tags with divs on the 60 odd .aspx pages.

How should I proceed? I have long term maintainability in mind, so a master page is the obvious solution. Are there any css parsers which can ease this conversion?

Thank you.
-Dhruv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any tool that's going to make this terribly easy for you.

My best advice would be to bite the bullet and upgrade to an ASP.NET 3.5 or 4.0 project so you can take advantage of the advances in .NET since that web site was built.

In the grand scheme of things, 60 pages isn't a huge amount.  Create the new Master Page (s), then just strip out all the non-content sections of those 60 pages and surround them in `<asp:Content` tags.

I bet you'll find it's a lot less work than you fear right now, and more importantly, it will pay dividends every time you have to update the site from now on.

Comment: Thank you, I've decided to upgrade to 4.0. To ease the task of extracting form elements from .aspx and injecting within <asp:content tags, I'm going to use Python.